# Let items pass at a fixed rate from a variable-rate stream

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

I got a stream of items and for each item an overall rate is updated. How can I decide based on this rate and a constant target rate if an item should pass or be rejected?

I started off using

$$
p_{pass} = \frac{target\_rate}{current\_rate}
$$

but this seems to skew the results, as the rate I get out of it is about 60% of the target rate.

Is there a way to determine if an item can pass to achieve the target rate for this variable-rate stream?

Comment: By current rate do you mean the mean rate until this point ( = $\text{total bits sent} \over \text{total time}$ )?

Comment: exactly, it is the rate until that point, approximated with ewma

Comment: How about accepting whenever the rate is too low, and rejecting whenever the rate is too high (bang bang)?